# Adding gravity in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want there to be a constant downward acceleration on player1. Everything I commented out were my attempts at creating gravity. I left in my last attempt because it seemed pretty close, but it's still not right.

Also, how would I make it so that when a key is released, player1 would continue to move, but stop accelerating? I tried an `if` statement where I checked that no keys were being pressed, but then I didn't know how to make player1 move at a constant velocity in the same direction it was going, so I just took it out.

Also, why does player1 get "stuck" on the edge of the screen sometimes? My best guess on this one is that it has something to do with pygame itself.

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 30


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, surface, accel, gravity):
        self.surface = surface
        self.accel = accel
        self.gravity = gravity
        self.x_mag = 0
        self.y_mag = 0
        self.x_dir = 0
        self.y_dir = 0
        self.vel = {"x_vel":
                        {"x_mag": self.x_mag, "x_dir": self.x_dir},
                    "y_vel":
                        {"y_mag": self.y_mag, "y_dir": self.y_dir}}
        self.x_pos = (screen_width / 2)
        self.y_pos = (screen_height / 2)
        self.pos = {"x_pos": self.x_pos, "y_pos": self.y_pos}
        self.size = (10, 10)

    def move_right(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 1
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 0

        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] += self.accel
        self.pos["x_pos"] += (self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] * self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"])

    def move_left(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 1
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 0

        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] -= self.accel
        self.pos["x_pos"] += (self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] * self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"])

    def move_up(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 0
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 1

        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] -= self.accel
        self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"])

    def move_down(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 0
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 1

        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] += self.accel
        self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"])

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move_up()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.move_left()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move_down()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.move_right()

        if self.pos["x_pos"] <= 0 or self.pos["x_pos"] >= screen_width:
            self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] *= -1
            self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 0

        if self.pos["y_pos"] <= 0 or self.pos["y_pos"] >= screen_height:
            self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] *= -1
            self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 0

        #self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] += self.gravity
        #self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"])
        self.pos["y_pos"] *= self.gravity

        self.character = pygame.Rect((self.pos["x_pos"], self.pos["y_pos"]), self.size)
        self.character.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 255, 255), self.character)

    def reset(self):
        (x_pos, y_pos) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.pos["x_pos"] = x_pos
        self.pos["y_pos"] = y_pos
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] = 0
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] = 0


# class Gravity(Character):
#     def __init__(self, accel_due_to_grav):
#         self.accel_due_to_grav = accel_due_to_grav
#
#     def active(self):
#         self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] += self.accel_due_to_grav
#         self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"])

def main():
    player1 = Character(screen, .5, .5)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    player1.reset()

        # grav01 = Gravity(.01)
        # grav01.active()

        player1.move()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        player1.display()

        pygame.display.update(screen_rect)
        clock.tick(fps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary for `self.vel`, why not just access the variables directly?

Comment: Why does this make me want to type [`import antigravity`](http://xkcd.com/353/)?

Comment: @sweeneyrod It just makes more sense to me to use a dictionary. I like keeping all of the velocity variables in one "thing"

Comment: At least use some string constants for accessing the value in the dictionary... or better, create a class for this. Also, what is `x_dir`? Shouldn't having separate x and y values be enough?

Comment: why do you multiplicate the position with the gravity? this makes no sense. Try adding the gravity * delta T to acceleration where delta T denotes the time sionce the last frame. Then you just need to apply the acceleration in every frame where you did not receive any user input

Comment: @Lukas Häfliger I tried replacing `self.pos["y_pos"] *= self.gravity` with `self.accel += self.gravity * clock.tick(fps)`, but that works even less.

Comment: A 2-tuple is 'one "thing"'! And surely `velocity = (3, -4)` is easier to understand and use than `velocity = {'x_vel': {'x_mag': 3, 'x_dir': 1), 'y_vel': {'y_mag': 4, 'y_dir': -1}}`?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've been avoiding doing that because I didn't know what a 2-tuple was (I kind of think I get it now, though) and also because I wanted to re-write as little of my code as possible. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did that, but now it's not accelerating for some reason. I don't really want to create another question just for that, so would you (or anyone) mind looking at [my code](http://pastebin.com/unyHSNin) and telling me why it's no longer accelerating?

Comment: How can it accelerate when you reset e.g. `x_vel=1` each time through `move_...`? Remember that `vel` is now `mag * dir`: to reverse e.g. `y` direction use `self.velocity = (self.velocity[0], self.velocity[1] * -1)`. Ditch the extra variables (e.g. `self.x_vel`) and dictionaries (e.g. `self.pos`) and just have three 2-tuples: `self.pos=(screen_width/2, screen_height/2); self.velocity=(0,0); self.acceleration=(0,0)`. Only *update* these in the `move` methods, *don't* reset them.

Comment: Guys, please refrain from working and commenting on external code here.

Answer (score 3):

### Motivation

Without boring you with too much physics: For constant accelerations (such as gravity on the surface of the earth) we have that `v = v_0 + a*t` (where `v_0` is the velocity you have before gravity acts on you (for example standing on a tower before you jump off - not recommended)

For constant velocity (this means there is NO acceleration - example: ice-skating), your position changes with `x = x_0 + v*t`.

If you want to know how the position changes when you apply some acceleration and have some velocity: `x = x_0 + v_0*t + 0.5*a*t²`

---

### Application in the Game

If you have a velocity in the game and an acceleration and you want to know how the position of you character needs to change, you can set `t = 1/30` (for example, if you compute it for every frame) and know that **in the next frame your character will be at position `x = x_old + v*t + 0.5*a*t²` and his velocity will be `v = v_old + a*t`** (this of course is only an approximation, but plenty good enough for a game)

---

### Your code

The Gravity class was almost there. At least for the y-direction. You can compute the displacement in x-direction in the same manner but ofc without gravity. With the reworked code you provided in the comment, I'd give it a try to just add this function to the `class Character(object)` definition and call it in `main()` before you call display.

```
def apply_gravity(self):
    timestep = 1./30 # or something else to your liking
    self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] += self.accel_due_to_grav * timestep
    self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"]) * timestep
    self.pos["y_pos"] += 0.5* self.accel_due_to_grav * timestep**2
```

---

### Further Remark

Also, if you don't want the movement to look like the character is ice-skiting you could either introduce friction (a small acceleration in the opposite direction of the velocity) or *damp* the velocity (multiply it by something like 0.9 in every timestep)

Comment: I re-did my code a little bit like @jonrsharpe said, so I wasn't able to just able to copy/paste your Gravity class, but I gave it a shot. Here's [my code](http://pastebin.com/74UqHhWL). I have no clue how to call the gravity class now, though. If you wouldn't mind taking a look at my code and leading me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I updated my response to fit into your reworked code. You could give it a try to just to put the function into the `class Character(object)` definition and call it in `main()` before you display the character. Hope it works.

Comment: [Here's what I tried](http://pastebin.com/FttE9gjw). It doesn't work. If you wouldn't mind taking a look at it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: When you write this `1/30` you get 0 because it divides two integers and gives you an integer (rounded down). You need to write `1./30` to get an actual float. Also put the `gravity` value to something like 10  for it to fall at reasonable speeds.

Comment: @user3162859 Off Topic: [I moved some things around](http://pastebin.com/rZaTmmkz) to separate the part of the code that advances the scene and the rest. Have a look at it, you might like it. Anyhow, I guess your question has been answered... :)